# How to find all $p$ congruences such that $(\frac{-5}{p})$ are quadratic residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am self-studying number theory and came across the question asked by another user in this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216901/determining-prime-numbers-p-which-satisfy-quadratic-residues-modulo-p). Specifically part (b).

My initial solution is to use the fact that the Legendre Symbol is completely multiplicative to split $(\frac{-5}{p})$ = $(\frac{-1}{p})*(\frac{5}{p})$, then follow the same steps to compute $(\frac{5}{p})$. Since $(\frac{-1}{p})$ is equal to 1 if $p \equiv 1\bmod\ 4$ and $-1$ if $p \equiv 3\bmod\ 4$, my idea was to use the CRT to find solutions that satisfy the congruence system. However, I am not sure this is the right next step. Any hint as to how I should go about solving this question?

Comment: Well, why not try your method?  It's easy to test small primes so you should be able to confirm or refute your solution.

Comment: I did! For one specific case, I got that $p \equiv 1\ mod\ 20$. After picking a few $p$s that satisfy the congruence, gives the correct result. I just want to make sure this is the right way of thinking on how to solve problems like this one.

Comment: Well, that's not the full solution.  As a useful sanity check:  once you have found the right modulus (and you are correct, that's $20$) then exactly half the coprime residues will work.  Since $\varphi(20)=8$,  there ought to be four coprime residues that work.  You have found one.

Comment: Just for an example:  with $p=3$, we have $-5\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ so $-5$ is definitely a square $\pmod 3$.  And with $p=7$, we have $-5\equiv 2 \pmod 7$ which is again a square.

Comment: the primes you want are either $p = u^2 + 5 v^2$  with integers $u,v$   or $p = 2 u^2 + 2 uv + 3 v^2 .$   For the second one, note that we allow $u,v$ positive and negative. Try some

Comment: @lulu I see... Wouldn't there be 8 different solutions since "5 on p" has 4 solutions itself, then "-1 on p" has 2, thus 8 solution classes?

Comment: You could compute $\left(\frac5p\right)$ using quadratic reciprocity

Comment: There are only eight coprime residues $\pmod {20}$.  Look at the solution for $\left(\frac 5p\right)$ that you linked to. There, the relevant modulus is $5$, we have four coprime classes, and two of those work.

Comment: @lulu I see! So my 4 solutions would be $p \equiv \pm 1$ mod $20$ and $p \equiv \pm 9$ mod $20$. I just checked a few primes that satisfy these congruences, and the all work. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Do they?  $p=11$ satisfies your congruences as $11\equiv -9 \pmod {20}$, yet $n^2\equiv -5 \pmod {11}$ has no solution.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose I didn't check $p=11$. What could I have done wrong? I don't think I made a numeric mistake anywhere in my calculations.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I see my mistake. I forgot to take into account when both   legendre symbols evaluate to $-1$. My new solutions are $p \equiv 1, 3, 7, 9$ mod $20$. Does this look right?

Comment: Yes, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Supplements_to_Quadratic_Reciprocity)